# How do we make arrays in awk?

Tags: arrays, awk

```
{
    k = 0
    x = 0
    fracon = (10/2)+1
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 1100 ; j++)
        {
            if (j <= fracon)
                scal[j]= j-x

            else
                k= k + 1
            scal[j]= j - (2*k)
            {
                if (scal[j] == 1)
                    fracon= fracon+11
                {
                    if (j % 11 == 0)
                        x=x+11
                    k=k+0.5
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's all. I used the above code to generate the following array. It works in Matlab, but it does not work in awk.

```
array= [1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: Not clear, why do you want to generate an array with `awk` could you please do let us know more clear requirement?

Comment: It's not clear where the blocks start or end.  Can you describe the algorithm in words or as a mathematical formula?

Comment: I want to generate this array = [1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6] and so on.

Comment: I've fixed your indentation. There is at least one block that isn't required (the one that starts on line 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way of generating the same sequence

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=20;i++) {k=i%11+1; printf "%s ", (k<7?k:12-k)}; print ""}'

1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2
```

not sure what you want is just repeated on a 11 element cycle or not; difficult to say based on limited sample.

or without `awk`

```
$  yes $({ seq 6; seq 5 -1 1; } | paste -sd' ') | head -100 | paste -sd' '

1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 ...
```

with square brackets

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "["; 
             for(i=0;i<=1100;i++) {k=i%11+1; printf "%s ", (k<7?k:12-k)}; 
             printf "]\n"}'

[1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 5 4 3 2 1 ]
```

Stuffing these values into a large array is not optimal, you can write a function to return the indexed value easily

```
$ awk 'function k(i,_i) {_i=i%11+1; return _i<7?_i:12-_i}  
       BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=25;i++) print k(i)}'
```

in the real code, you'll use `k(i)` instead of printing. Note the array index starts from 0.

N.B. the `_i` is a local variable in the `awk` function; you don't need to use in the call syntax.

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfectly. How can I print as an arry?

Comment: Just add square brackets.

Comment: like : $ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<=20;i++) {[k]=i%11+1; printf "%s ", ([k]<7?k:12-[k])}; print ""}'
 it does not work

Comment: Also what do you mean by "array", just print in that format or are you going to use it in `awk` for other purposes?

Comment: OK, just to make sure, this script is just printing the values in the array format.  It's not an array (and definitely not in `bash` expected format to be converted automatically).  If the consumption is in `awk` there is no need to create an array, just create a function that will return you the corresponding value for the given index.

Comment: Can I write it as k[i]=... because I want to call each element in the array to use it on other calculation.

Comment: that's the issue with piecemeal questions!  The optimal answer depends on what else is happening. Here, I wouldn't do an array, I would write a function as I mentioned and call syntax will be with round brackets.  `k(i)` as in any other function call.